# How to pipe a dataset into a pmap?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

My tibble looks like this :

```
  dataset <- tibble(country = sample(c(11,23,18,17,12,19,30,16,14,13,15),7679,replace = T),yrbirth = floor(runif(7679,1900,1970)))
```

and I have two help vectors to check conditons

```
country_code <- c(11,23,18,17,12,19,30,16,14,13,15)

crit_year <- c(1947,1969,1957,1953,1948,1958,1958,1949,1959,1947,1947)
```

I have a function to do the mutation

```
f_g_treat <- function(dataset, country_code, crit_year){
  dataset_new <- dataset %>%
    filter(country == country_code) %>%
    mutate(treatment = ifelse(yrbirth >=crit_year-7,'Treat','Contr'))
  return(dataset_new$treatment)
}
```

Now I want to pipe dataset into the pmap but it seems that is throws me an error. My idea was this

```
dataset <- dataset %>%
 mutate(treatment =
 pmap(list(country_code, crit_year), ~f_g_treat(dataset = ., country_code = ..1, crit_year = ..2 )) %>%
           unlist() )
```

Doing so throws me the folling error :

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `treatment`.
> x no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
> i Input `treatment` is ``%>%`(...)`.

When I try :

```
dataset <- mutate(dataset, treatment =
                pmap(list(country_code, crit_year), ~f_g_treat(dataset = dataset, country_code = ..1, crit_year = ..2 )) %>%
                unlist() )
```

everything works fine and I get the expected vector. So I believe I use the anonymous object passing `.` wrong in this part. Can someone help me with that?

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you want to pass the entire dataset to every call of `f_g_treat`? The example that works fine according to you, does not run on my machine.

Comment: So my expected output should be the dataset with a third column called treatment. Which shoud equal the vector generated by pmap(...) %>% unlist

Yes, I need the datast in eacht iteration because I need to filter first for some arguments before I mutate.

Comment: @Bas Found the problem with the MWE. Now it should work on your side. Besides, the problem in OP still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific question, `do` solves your problem:

```
do(dataset, mutate(., treatment =
                    pmap(list(country_code, crit_year), function(x, y) f_g_treat(dataset = ., country_code = x, crit_year = y )) %>%
                    unlist() )   )
```

Note I had to make the parameters of the function in `pmap` explicit (`x`, `y`) to avoid overwriting the `.` that `do` created.

I don't think the output is correct though, nor is it in your working example. The `treatment` column is pasted in the wrong order (namely the order of `country_code, crit_year`), rather than the order in the original data frame.

A better way to do this is via a join:

```
country_crit_year <- tibble(country = country_code, crit_year = crit_year)
dataset %>% 
  left_join(country_crit_year, by = "country") %>% 
  mutate(treatment = if_else(yrbirth >= crit_year-7, "Treat", "Contr"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
dataset %>%
  mutate(treatment = pmap(list(country_code, crit_year), 
                          f_g_treat, 
                          dataset = .) %>% unlist())
```